# How to dim UIColor same as system

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicolor

How to dim a `UIColor` exectly the same as the system dims tint colors? (like when presenting a popover)

So i can dim the background exactly the same as the system would do (in this case)

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {

    super.tintColorDidChange()

    if tintAdjustmentMode == .dimmed {
        backgroundColor = // DIM originalBackgroundColor
    } else {
        backgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor
    }

}
```

Comment: What the system does is anybody's guess, but why not just desaturate the color?

Comment: i want a system consistent solution...

Comment: I'm sure you do, but as I said, what the system does is anybody's guess. There is no public API for what the system is doing when it dims a color unless that color is a tint color (and even then you do not know what the resulting color _is_).